# AngularJS Routing doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need help with routing in AngularJS. I am new and don't understend why it doesn't work.
I have a small application with to pages.
my app.js:

```
var app = angular.module("suggestionBox", ["ngRoute"]);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            controller: 'HomeController',
            templateUrl: 'views/home.html'
        })
        .when('/suggestion/:id', {
            controller: 'SuggestionController',
            templateUrl: 'views/suggestion.html'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
});
```

my view:

```
<form ng-submit="addSuggestion()" style="margin-top: 50px">
    <h3> Submit Your Suggestion </h3>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Great ideas here" ng-model="data.title">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Suggest</button>
</form>
<div class="posts-wraper">
    <div class="suggestion" ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy: '-upvotes'">
        <h3>{{ post.title }}</h3>
        <div>
            <p>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" ng-click="upVote(post)"></span> Upvotes: {{post.upvotes}}
            </p>
            <a class="comment" href="#/suggestion/{{$index}}">Comments</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

main page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Suggestion Box</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/angular-route.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="suggestionBox">

<div class="col-md-2"></div>
<div class="col-md-8">
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2"></div>

<!-- Modules -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>

<!-- Controllers -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/HomeController.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/SuggestionController.js"></script>

<!-- Services -->
<script src="js/services/suggestions.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

And when I'm on home page and want to go to /suggestion/:id I click reference and nothing happen. But I have the following url: "http:// localhost:8080/#!/#suggestion%2F0" and stay at the home page. If I type url by hand like this: "http:// localhost:8080/#!/suggestion/0" all is well and I go to suggestion page. Then I press back:

```
<a href="#/">Back</a>
```

and it works! I am on home page, but url is: "http:// localhost:8080/#!/#%2F"
I don't know why! Please help me with it.

Comment: don't put `#` in your `href` tags.

Comment: Change it to newest Angular version. which version are you currently using?

Comment: @MMK makes a good point;  you aren't showing what angular version you have, but it is **very important** to keep the angular version and the angular-route version the same.  angular 1.2.28 is an outdated legacy release, not really recommended for new projects.

Comment: @ruslan-krupenko does it make sense?

Comment: Angular version is 1.6.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How about something like that**  check the [Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/zwcSPZI0baCXHSNv4ZbT/) if code snippet doesn't make any sense also pay attention to markup changes in the index, home and suggestion.html in plunker. You can edit the plunker and see the URL changes by launching the *plunker preview in separate window*.

***app.js***

```
 var app = angular.module("SuggestionBox", ['ngRoute']);
    app.config(["$routeProvider", "$locationProvider", function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
        $locationProvider.hashPrefix(''); // magic line
        $routeProvider
        .when('/',{
            controller: "HomeController",
            templateUrl: "views/home.html"
        })
        .when('/suggestion/:id',{
            controller: "SuggestionController",
            templateUrl: "views/suggestion.html"
        })        
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
    }]);
```

Comment: It works well ! I'm great appreciate you. Now url looks fine. No more '!' next to '#'. What did it mean? I don't know

Comment: @ruslan-krupenko In newer version of angular 1.6.1 angular guys decided to set $locationProvider.hashPrefix('"!");  so by setting  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');  in app.js,  you override what is set by default. I hope it clears it up.

Comment: Thanks for explanation.